# Al activar una función, no devuelve nada que se muestre en el DOM

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Estoy comenzando en el mundo de la programación con REACTJS y a continuación el problema.

La idea es: Al apretar el botón de "añadir a carrito" se muestren 2 botones en el DOM, "Añadir a carrito" (redireccionar a /cart) y "Añadir a carrito y seguir comprando" (redireccionando a /homePage).

Este es el botón del DOM:

```js
<button onClick={seguirCompra}>Añadir al Carro</button>
```

La función `seguirCompra()`:

```js
function seguirCompra() 
{
   return valorCount ? onAdd() : (text) => borrarTitulo(text);
}
```

El valor del `valorCount`, se le da cuando se usa el contador para elegir la cantidad de productos asignados (por ende, sí traería un valor `true`) entonces se debería ejecutar la función `onAdd()`

`onAdd()`:

```js
function onAdd(){
return (
  <div className="seguirCompra">
      {console.log("valorCount es ", valorCount)} 
//Tengo este console.log para ver si llega a entrar a la función, y si lo hace
      
      <Link to="/cart">
      <button
          className="btnSeguirCompra"
          onClick={() => agregarProdCart(productComplete())}
      >
          Ir al carrito y finalizar compra
      </button>
      </Link>

      <Link to="/">
      <button className="btnSeguirCompra">Seguir comprando</button>
      </Link>
  </div>
)}
```

Entonces entra a la función, pero no devuelve nada que se muestre en el DOM, y no entiendo por qué.

Soluciones intentadas:

1-Antes tenía todo en distintos archivos .js pasados por props, lo que hice para "optimizarlo" fue ponerlo todo en el mismo dejando más claro el código, pero antes funcionaba y ahora no...
2-A la función `seguirCompra()` la tenía declarada dentro del `onClick`, pensé que capaz no funcionaba por eso, y empecé a hacerlas por separado, **que una function llame a otra**
3-Intenté borrar la función `(text) => borarrTitulo(text)` pero tampoco funcionó.

Entiendo que el problema viene de alguna propiedad que impida que se muestre en el DOM, pero desconozco cuál será.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

veo que tienes una confusión de cómo react maneja y renderiza su jsx, para poder mostrar el contenido de tu componente funcional "onAdd" debes llamarlo desde el jsx de tu componente padre, en este caso donde está tu button, deberia quedar algo como esto:

```html
<>
<button onClick={seguirCompra}>Añadir al Carro</button>
valorCount && <onAdd />
</>
```

luego tu función "seguirCompra" debería quedar así:

```html
function seguirCompra() {
   !valorCount && borrarTitulo(text);
}
```

Saludos!